# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}} $ converge uniformly on $]-1,1-\delta]$ with $0<\delta<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, power-series

> Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}} $ be a power serie with
>   the radius of converge $R=1$ . Show that it converge uniformly on
>   $]-1,1-\delta]$ with $0<\delta<1$

Can anyone check my Proof please.

We will proof that the serie converge by splitting the interval in two parts like this $]-1,0[$ ,$[0,1-\delta]$.

Let's first look at the case where $x$ is on the interval $]-1,0[$  .

We can see that the power serie is alternating because $x<0$.

There's a Theorem that say if a serie $\{ a_n \}$ is alternating wth positive terms and

$lim_n{\to_\infty} \{a_n\} = 0$, then it implies that the serie 
$\sum(-1)^na_n$ converge.

Also if $ S_n= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k (-1)^{k+1}$ and $ S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (-1)^{n+1} $ then $|S-S_n| \leq a_{n+1}$.

With the previous Theorem,  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n|x|^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}} $ converge to a limit $S(x)$.

We will now show that the serie converge uniformly on ]-1,0[.

Let's choose $\epsilon>0$ , we must find a natural number $N$ such that $n>N$

$$|S(x) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n|x|^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}} | < \epsilon .$$

$$|S(x) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n|x|^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}} | \leq \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{ \sqrt{(n+1)+1}} \leq \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n}} <\epsilon $$

We get $N=\lfloor  \displaystyle \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \rfloor$.

It follow that the serie converge uniformly on $]-1,0[$.

---

Now let's work on the interval 
$x \in [0,1-\delta]$.

$\frac{x^n}{ \sqrt{n+1} } \leq \frac{(1-\delta)^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}}$

where $\frac{(1-\delta)^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}} \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty}0$

By the Weierstrass M-test   $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}} $ converge uniformly on $[0,1-\delta]$.

---

Since it converge uniformly on both interval, we conclude that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{ \sqrt{n+1}} $ converge uniformly on $]-1,1-\delta ]$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Proof verication

Comment: Which part? $ $

Comment: in the interval $]-1,0[$

Comment: Which parts of your own proof make you uneasy? (Come! Please stop to take the site for a free proof checking service...)

Comment: well since nobody help me the first time I posted it, I get my own answer .